# ie7 lang attribute compatibility

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, cross-browser, lang

I am setting the lang attribute on my html tag and body tag. I then explicitly use it in my css for targeting css at particular languages.

This works fine in IE8, IE9, FF & Chrome and works a treat. However it does not work in IE7. Anyone know why and a possible work around for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The attribute selector such as

```
[lang|="en"]
```

has buggy support in IE8 and lower. You will have to target the element by other means!